# "declaration has no storage class or type specifier" in C++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ through the book (5th Edition),today I encounter a problem when doing the exercise 12.6.

The code is shown below, the error is `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`. But the program can run normally. The error locates at the last line on '}'.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<new>

using namespace std;

vector<int>* func(){
    return new vector<int>();
}

void read_vec(istream &in, vector<int>* vp){
    int i;
    while(in>>i)
        vp->push_back(i);
}

void print_vec(vector<int>* vp){
    for(int i:*vp)
        cout<<i<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    auto vec = func();
    cout<<"Enter a sequence of integers"<<endl;
    read_vec(cin,vec);
    print_vec(vec);
    delete vec;
    vec = nullptr;

    system("pause");
}
```

I have searched the message, but still cannot figure out where my code is wrong.

I would be appreciative for all hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the standard library header `<cstdlib>` to use `system`.

Add

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

at the top of the file. Then, use `std::system` instead of just `system`.

```
std::system("pause");
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But the warning remains after adding cstdlib. BTW, I always ignore this library in other exercises when using "system", but no error...

Comment: I just tried another online debugger, no warning either.. Then it must be the weird warning from VScode plugins....  Thank you very much, bro!